# Mobile Offline Sync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, realm-js

I'm currently working on a React Native application, the server is already implemented and my app should implement offline sync, I'm planning to integrate `realm` on the mobile device to deal with the offline data and pushing the data to the implemented server when the device is online. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying also to make some kind of offline sync. A calendar app that works offline.

I'm developing it on ionic 4 using sqlite.

Basically, what I did is: I keep a variable with my last update timestamp.

**Part 1**

Get activities.

A service is running on the background, getting from the backend activities that their creation timestamp is later than the mobile last update timestamp.

**Part 2**

Every time the user create an activity I add the `timestamp` to the activities table and a flag called `synced` that is `true` / `false`.

Another service scans the table for `synced === 'false'` and does the `POST` request.

Hope I helped.